# SharePoint Online - user id causing problem - userdisp.aspx?ID=

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user, ad, pnp-powershell

After the support team (third-party) deleted a user and created the same user in another OU we're having some problem.

Old ID is showing up on "Created by" on some document set, see picture below:
[image]

this id is different from Modified by

[image]

, even  it is the same user. This is causing problem when trying to update those "files". I've not found any solution to clean up in this matter so I've tried to change the created by field using PnP Powershell without any luck.

```
$user = Get-PnPUser .....
Set-PnPListItem -List "knall" -id 7 -Value @{"Author" = $user}
```

Problem is that $user is not a SPFieldUserValue, I've tried to use EnsureUser without any luck. But it would be nice to fix this another way.

```
Move-SPUser –Identity "DOMAIN\OldUserName" –NewAlias "Domain\NewUserName"
```

The command over I don't know if will work since the "users" have the same domain\username..... Will it work in SP Online?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the ListItem level Author update goes, try this:

```
$user = Get-PnPUser .....
Set-PnPListItem -List "knall" -id 7 -Value @{"Author" = $user.LoginName}
```

Comment: I've already tried that without any luck ($user.LoginName)

Comment: Is $user resolving properly? And what kind of list is "knall"?

Comment: Yes, $user is resolving properly and it shows when I get the FieldValues but does not show in the document library. It's a document set I'm trying to change